# Multiple Lstm after and before fully connected

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have written an architecture in Keras which works fine, but I want to implement the same architecture in tensorflow. I am writing the architecture in tensorflow but I am not able to create multiple layers of LSTM.

Here is the keras code:

```
input_data1 = Input(inshape, dtype='float32', name='input1')
encoder1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='encoder1'), name='encoder1_TD')(input_data1)

lstm1 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='lstm1')(encoder1)
lstm2 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='lstm2')(lstm1)

intermediate_data = TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation='linear', name='decoder1'), name='decoder_TD1')(lstm2)
output_data = TimeDistributed(Dense(12, activation='linear', name='decoder2'), name='decoder_TD2')(intermediate_data)

model = Model(input_data, output_data)
print(model.summary())
return model
```

Can anyone please help me out with the tensorflow architecture of this? I am not able to understand the usage of MultiRNNCell. It is giving me an error whenever I use 2 or more layers of LSTM.

```
input shape = (batch_size, timesteps, 4)

output shape = (batch_size, timesteps, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like recent changes [in tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide) makes it similar to the keras, also, new tutorials focused on the keras-like solutions.

If you need some "old-style" tensorflow stacked LSTM, you can use `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` (now it's deprecated and replaced with `tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells`):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib
from tensorflow.nn import dynamic_rnn

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, time_steps, num_features])
label_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, time_steps, num_labels])
# dense layer is broadcasted automatically to time-distributed data 
dense_data = tf.layers.dense(input_data, 128, activation='relu')

with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
    lstm1 = tensorflow.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(256, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm2 = tensorflow.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(256, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm3 = tensorflow.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(256, state_is_tuple=True)
    # or even more layers
    # group them into one cell
    multi_cell = tensorflow.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm1, lstm2, lstm3], state_is_tuple=True)
    rnn_result, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_cell, dense_data, dtype=tf.float32)

td_data_1 = tf.layers.dense(rnn_result, 128, activation='linear')
td_data_2 = tf.layers.dense(rnn_result, 12, activation='linear')
```

Now you should define some loss, but it's not clear which loss you're planning to use, so i omit this part (based on some features, it could be [`sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) (after all, it's not runnable example, but I can provide one for some standart dataset like MNIST or so, if you need):

```
loss = tf.nn...
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

Initialization and train (simplified):

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

for i in range(len(x_tr) // batch_size):
    sess.run(
        train_op,
        feed_dict={
            input_data: x_tr[i*batch_size:i*batch_size+batch_size],
            output_data: y_tr_cat[i*batch_size:i*batch_size+batch_size],

        }
    )
```

Notice please if you don't need stack deprecated tensorflow layers and require some solution for 2.0 version.